# external link content not appearing inAppBrowser view

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser, phonegap

I built an app where user can upload any kind of documents. After successful uploading I am sending back corresponding url as a response. By using that response I was showing uploaded document in preview mode. Now my problem is

After I click on that preview, I want to show that document with in App instead of mobile browser by using inAppBrowser cordova plugin. For this I written following code . It's working as I expect in IOS devices not in android.  To debug the use-case I just hard-coded some google image url and tried . I could see that image **inAppBrowser** view even in android. Only problem with documents which user uploaded through my application.

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

If something is problem w.r.t permissions, it should not work even in IOS but it's working. So I guess There was a problem with Android. How can I achieve this.

It looks like below, When I click on external link. I couldn't able to see content but I can see URL.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: To open the file inside the app I think you can use cordova -plugin-file-opener2.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

You may need to add the whitelist plugin. This would explain why it works on iOS but not on android.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Installation

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Then in your config xml check you have this line:

```
 <access origin="*" />
```

**Original**

Have you hooked the in app browser to window.open like this?

```
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
```

This will enable any window.open calls to be routed to the in app browser.

Also you will need to add the location argument to the window.open call:

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Also ensure you are waiting until deviceready has fired before using the window.open method. I have found some devices load the plugins faster than others.

Comment: Edited to add more information let me know if it helps.

Comment: Tried your approach but no luck, mat be I guess as per @jcesarmobile comment It's not possible to do in android.

Comment: whitelist doesn't affect inAppBrowser. The problem is the Android WebView can't render those files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Android webview, it can't render some files (most of them), just simple files like images and maybe txt.

Your options are to use `'_system'` instead of `'_blank'`, that will launch an intent to the system so other app can open the file. The other option is to use a file opener plugin instead of inAppBrowser plugin (there are a lot of file opener plugins)

Comment: As per your approach, even hard coded image url also should not come in webView, but it's appearing. Any reason on this.

Comment: I said, it can only render some simple files like images and maybe txt files, but not complex files like pdf or doc